# Choosing between past perfect and present perfect

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

Why Is it incorrect to say *had not been seen* in this sentence?

> The people next door disappeared six months ago. *They have not been seen* since then.

Comment: Who told you that was incorrect? You need to add more context to this question. If this is from an exam question, tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past perfect places an action in the past in relation to a time which is also completely in the past.

> The people next door disappeared six months ago and **had not been seen until last Tuesday** when they descended in a tractor beam from an extraterrestrial spaceship.

In your sentence, you say **since then**, and so there is no explicit mention of a *past* time in relation to which their not being seen is presented. The phrase **since then** extends from the past up to the *present*. Your sentence calls for the present perfect. With the past perfect, the sentence is semantically incomplete. The listener is expecting some mention of their being seen again at some point in the recent past. The listener might *infer* that they have now been seen again, to complete your meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The **past perfect** refers to something which has happened (or was the case) entirely in the past. If you use the sentence "They *had not been seen* since then," it implies that they have been seen (recently) as their state of not being seen *is no longer the case*.

However, using the **present perfect** in this context relates to something which *began in the past and still continues in the present*. Saying "They *have not been seen* since then" means that they weren't seen in the past, and still aren't seen in the present.

Take another simpler example, "I *have not been* to Japan." This implies that I have never gone to Japan, and I'm still not there. If I say "I *had not been* to Japan," this implies that at some point I did go to Japan, where I had not gone previously.

Comment: Usually the past perfect though isn't in isolation the way you are using it. It is typically used in conjunction with another clause containing usually a past tense verb